# Convert std::variant to another std::variant with super-set of types

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++17, variant

I have a `std::variant` that I'd like to convert to another `std::variant` that has a super-set of its types. Is there a way of doing it than that allows me to simply assign one to the other?

```
template <typename ToVariant, typename FromVariant>
ToVariant ConvertVariant(const FromVariant& from) {
    ToVariant to = std::visit([](auto&& arg) -> ToVariant {return arg ; }, from);
    return to;
}

int main()
{
    std::variant<int , double> a;
    a = 5;
    std::variant <std::string, double, int> b;
    b = ConvertVariant<decltype(b),decltype(a)>(a);
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to be able to simply write `b = a` in order to do the conversion rather than going through this complex casting setup. Without polluting the `std` namespace.

Edit: Simply writing `b = a` gives the following error:

```
error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::variant<int,double>' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 

note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::variant<std::string,int,double>, std::variant<int,double>)'
```

Comment: If `U` is universe of all the types , and P has U, isn't P equals U ?

I am having trouble understanding what problem you're trying to solve, may be I'm dumb :|

Comment: Try compiling `b=a` directly, to see the issue.

Comment: The error is as follows:
error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::variant<int,double>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::variant<std::string,int,double>, std::variant<int,double>)'

Comment: `b = ConvertVariant<decltype(b),decltype(a)>(a);` can be simplified to `b = ConvertVariant<decltype(b)>(a);` and if `decltype(b)` bothers you, you can have output parameter to your function to have something like  `ConvertVariantTo(a, b);`.

Comment: why isn't this conversion part of std::variant? If I understand correctly, Boost.Variant does have this functionality...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is an implementation of Yakk's second option:

```
template <class... Args>
struct variant_cast_proxy
{
    std::variant<Args...> v;

    template <class... ToArgs>
    operator std::variant<ToArgs...>() const
    {
        return std::visit([](auto&& arg) -> std::variant<ToArgs...> { return arg ; },
                          v);
    }
};

template <class... Args>
auto variant_cast(const std::variant<Args...>& v) -> variant_cast_proxy<Args...>
{
    return {v};
}
```

You might want to fine tune it for forwarding semantics.

And as you can see its use is simple:

```
std::variant<int, char> v1 = 24;
std::variant<int, char, bool> v2;

v2 = variant_cast(v1);
```

Comment: Can this construction be changed to support moving from the source variant?

Comment: @nyanpasu64 "you might want to fine tune it for forwarding semantics."

Answer (score 2):

Options:

- Write your own `variant` type, possibly inheriting from `std::variant`, that implements `operator=` and construction the way you want.  Some work has to be done, because `variant`'s constructors can do SFINAE tricks that might not work properly with your variant type; to that end, you want to do some SFINAE forwarding to base-variant yourself instead of naked `using` declarations.
- Write a better `ConvertVariant` that doesn't require the source/destination types to be listed.  You would return a convert helper template type that holds the source variant which has an `operator std::variant<Ts...>()&&` that calls something very much like your `ConvertVariant`.