# How to make a map key to be of two different data types?

Tags: c++, stdtuple, std-variant

I have a `std::unordered_map` container, where `Key` can be of two data types:

- 64-bit unsigned int
- tuple having (8-bit unsigned int, 8-bit unsigned int, 16-bit unsigned-int, 32-bit unsigned int)

But value is an object type that is the same with both the key types.

One thing I've tried is making the key a `std::variant` so that it can hold both the types.  Based on some condition check, key is being set to one of the types:

```
void A::a() {
    std::varaint<type1, type2> Id; //key

    if (condition) {
        Id = 64 bit unsigned value;
    }
    else {
        Id = tuple<.....>;
    }
}

unorderedmap[Id] = obj1;
// ^-- gives compile-time error
// (expecting Id specialized to either of the variant types)
```

Also, similar to this function there are multiple functions where we are doing find() on `unordered_map`.

```
unorderedmap.find(Id);
// ^-- Here also, compiler is throwing similar error
```

Is there a way to fix the std::variant, or should I use another approach?

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Why not use a `template`?

Comment: what is your question? "Any suggestions" is off-topic here. Working code is off-topic here. If you have a specific problem we can gladly help, you but you need to specify it and create a [MCVE]

Comment: Show your `unordered_map` declaration. Which `Hash` and `KeyEqual` do you use ?

Comment: What people mean when they say "complete and verifiable" is you shouldn't post code with spelling errors (`std::varaint`) or other obvious mistakes (using `Id` outside of the scope of `A::a()`).  If you want REAL help, you need to post REAL code.  You should be able to generate a small example that anyone could try compiling and get the *literal* exact error you are getting, and edit your question to provide that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

typedef std::variant<int, std::string> mytype;

std::unordered_map<mytype, int> m;

int main()
{
    m[5] = 20;
    std::cout << m[5];
    m["hey"] = 10;
    std::cout << m["hey"];
    mytype tmp = "hey";
    std::cout << m[tmp];
}
```

So the answer is basically: Make sure if you try indexing a map with a variant, the map's index is of the same variant type. If you use `get` or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203255/convert-stdvariant-to-another-stdvariant-with-super-set-of-types), you can even get it to work when `map` is a superset of the variant you want to use - closely emulating dynamic languages.

## EDIT:

If you want to support `std::tuple`, you have a couple options.

## Option 1

Just use `std::map` instead of `std::unordered_map`. It's unlikely you'll ever be able to see the `logN`, and from experience `std::map` will actually be faster (You also won't be murdered by rehashes that take a century, which happens every time `std::unordered_map` has to grow).

## Option 2

Keep using `std::unordered_map`, but implement hashing. An example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21439212/2574612), with the following adapted code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <unordered_map>
// #include "custom_tuple.h"

// CUSTOM_TUPLE.h
#include <tuple>

namespace std{
    namespace
    {

        // Code from boost
        // Reciprocal of the golden ratio helps spread entropy
        //     and handles duplicates.
        // See Mike Seymour in magic-numbers-in-boosthash-combine:
        //     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948780

        template <class T>
        inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, T const& v)
        {
            seed ^= hash<T>()(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
        }

        // Recursive template code derived from Matthieu M.
        template <class Tuple, size_t Index = std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1>
        struct HashValueImpl
        {
          static void apply(size_t& seed, Tuple const& tuple)
          {
            HashValueImpl<Tuple, Index-1>::apply(seed, tuple);
            hash_combine(seed, get<Index>(tuple));
          }
        };

        template <class Tuple>
        struct HashValueImpl<Tuple,0>
        {
          static void apply(size_t& seed, Tuple const& tuple)
          {
            hash_combine(seed, get<0>(tuple));
          }
        };
    }

    template <typename ... TT>
    struct hash<std::tuple<TT...>> 
    {
        size_t
        operator()(std::tuple<TT...> const& tt) const
        {                                              
            size_t seed = 0;                             
            HashValueImpl<std::tuple<TT...> >::apply(seed, tt);    
            return seed;                                 
        }                                              

    };
}
// END CUSTOM_TUPLE.h

typedef std::variant<std::string, std::tuple<int, bool>> mytype;

std::unordered_map<mytype, int> m;

int main()
{
    m[std::tuple{5, false}] = 20;
    std::cout << m[std::tuple{5, false}];
    m["hey"] = 10;
    std::cout << m["hey"];
    mytype tmp = "hey";
    std::cout << m[tmp];
}
```

You can put everything inside of the `namespace std{}` part inside of a header, and then just include that header wherever you want (I omitted include guards, so ofc add that as usual). If the standard ever catches up and implements tuple hashing, just remove the header file.

Comment: There are of course ways to fully encapsulate this and get guaranteed safety.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Ah, I misunderstood. I updated my answer.

Comment: the actual problem is that `std::tuple` doesn't have a `hash_map` specialization and consequentially neither does a `std::variant` that has a `std::tuple` as argument. So replace `std::string` with `std::tuple<int>` and the code won't compile.

Comment: @bolov How can hash_map specialization be done for tuple type?Any suggestions

Comment: @bvb I've updated my answer, see if it works for you.