# Convert std::variant to another std::variant with sub-set of types

Tags: c++

Given a variable of type `std::variant<A,B,C>`, I've checked that it does *not* contain `C`. How can I convert it to a `std::variant<A,B>`?

```
std::variant<A,B> convert(std::variant<A,B,C> value) {
  if (std::holds_alternative<C>(value)) {
    // die.
  }

  return ... // what to do here?
}
```

I know how to do the opposite (convert to a super set variant) using a visitor as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203255/convert-stdvariant-to-another-stdvariant-with-super-set-of-types), but that approach does not work for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run trough `std::visit`, use a receiving lambda expression which only "eats" the type you want and create your new variant type.

Hint:
As your converted variant type is maybe "empty", because you have to return something, even if the type from the incoming variant is not a valid one by your definition, you have to provide some "dummy type". For this purpose `std::monotype` is already defined.

Using a c++20 concept makes it easier, but I provide you also the "old fashioned" way with handcrafted lambdas:

```
struct A{};
struct B{};
struct C{};

using VARIANT_ALL = std::variant<A,B,C>;
using VARIANT_SUB = std::variant<std::monostate,A,B>;

template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };

template < typename CHECK_ME >
concept IS_WANTED = std::is_same_v<CHECK_ME, A> || std::is_same_v<CHECK_ME, B >;  

VARIANT_SUB GetSubset( const VARIANT_ALL& vin )
{
    return std::visit( overloaded
               {
                   []( const A& x ){ return VARIANT_SUB{x};},
                   []( const B& x ){ return VARIANT_SUB{x};},
                   []( auto&  ) { return VARIANT_SUB{};}
               }, vin 
              );
}

VARIANT_SUB GetSubset2( const VARIANT_ALL& vin )
{
    return std::visit( overloaded
               {
                   [] < IS_WANTED TYPE >( const TYPE& x ){ return VARIANT_SUB{x};},
                   []( auto&  ) { return VARIANT_SUB{};}
               }, vin 
              );
}

int main()
{
    VARIANT_ALL va=A{};
    VARIANT_ALL vb=B{};
    VARIANT_ALL vc=C{};

    auto vva = GetSubset( va );
    auto vvb = GetSubset( vb );
    auto vvc = GetSubset( vc );

    std::cout << std::holds_alternative<A>( vva ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::holds_alternative<B>( vvb ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::holds_alternative<std::monostate>( vvc ) << std::endl;

    auto vva2 = GetSubset2( va );
    auto vvb2 = GetSubset2( vb );
    auto vvc2 = GetSubset2( vc );

    std::cout << std::holds_alternative<A>( vva2 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::holds_alternative<B>( vvb2 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::holds_alternative<std::monostate>( vvc2 ) << std::endl;
}
```