# Convert std::variant<A, B> to std::variant<A, B, C>

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following code:

```
std::variant<A, B> foo();
std::variant<A, B, C> bar();
std::variant<A, B, C> foobar(bool a) {
    if (a) {
        return foo();
    } else {
        return bar();
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't compile on gcc:

```
error: could not convert ‘foo()’ from ‘variant<A, B>’ to ‘variant<A,B,C>’.
```

Is there an elegant way to convert `std::variant<A, B>` into `std::variant<A, B, C>`?

Comment: [std::static_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)

Comment: @Ripi2: That doesn't work. `variant` is not convertible to a `variant` of other types.

Comment: You could replace the return type with `auto` and use `if constexpr`.

Comment: A `std::variant<A, B>` is not a `std::variant<A, B, C>`. Different types. Why would you think you could cast between them? Remember: a cast doesn't *convert* anything. It just reinterprets bits through different glasses.

Comment: Note that the appropriate term here is **convert** (as in the error message), not **cast**. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: @PeteBecker I changed 'cast' to 'convert'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert std::variant to another std::variant with super-set of types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203255/convert-stdvariant-to-another-stdvariant-with-super-set-of-types) and from that answer `variant_cast(foo())` works juuust fine

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an elegant way to convert `std::variant<A, B>` into `std::variant<A, B, C>`?

No, I suppose.

The best I can imagine pass through `std::visit()`; something as

```
std::variant<A, B, C> foobar (bool a)
 {
   if (a) 
      return std::visit([](auto && val) -> std::variant<A, B, C>
                        { return {std::forward<decltype(val)>(val)}; },
                        foo());
   else
      return bar();
 }
```

A more general solution, could be a `convVariant()` function

```
template <typename R, typename T>
R convVariant (T && t)
 {
   return std::visit([](auto && val) -> R
                        { return {std::forward<decltype(val)>(val)}; },
                        std::forward<T>(t));
 }
```

so `foobar()` become

```
std::variant<A, B, C> foobar (bool a)
 {
   if (a) 
      return convVariant<std::variant<A, B, C>>(foo());
   else
      return bar();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In principle, the standard could allow implicit (if guaranteed successful) or explicit (otherwise) conversion from `std::variant<T...>` to `std::variant<U...>` if all types in the former occurred at least as often in the latter, as there is an unambiguous and obvious mapping.

Unfortunately, it simply doesn't.

Thus, you have to write your own function for converting.